# Unique Permissions

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I am facing some issues with unique permissions in SharePoint 2013,
I want a SP group X to have access only to particular folder in a library.

That group have edit permission to the site and this library inherits permission from the site.

So I broke library permission and then I removed group X from library permissions and I assigned group X to the required folder by breaking permission again.

Now group X have limited access to the library and Edit permission to the folder.

The problem is when the group member access the folder to which they have given access, they are getting access denied error. Kindly someone help me with this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check whether "**Limited-access user permission lockdown mode**" feature enable at site collection level.

If enable then please deactivate and check it.

Reference Link : https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/3039997/users-can-t-access-a-shared-folder-in-sharepoint-online

Answer (score 1):

Hi you need not break the permission at library level, for your scenario you just need item level permission, so break permission at item/folder level and remove all groups/User and grant the user/ group you need to grant the permission too.

Or if need break permission at library level you need to follow what Sam suggested.